# How can I view the page with the updated value on table in the view after adding the new record on the table

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to view the page after new records on the table inside the view. But after calling post method I can see only the record before updated even if the new records have already been added to the database. To see the new record on the view page I have to select the Bankholiday option again from the menu then only it call httpget method and shows the updated value. But I am trying to view page with new records just after calling the post method and after its update. I tried  with 'Return Redirect' to httpget , but it does not work for me since some styling issue problem when it call HttpGet().

Here is the code:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult BankHolidaySettings(int DEPT = 0, int YR = 0)
{
    return View(bankHoliday);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult BankHolidaySettings(BankHoliday bankHoliday)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        id =  _unitOfWork.BankHolidayRepo.AddBankHoliday(bankHolidayToAdd);

        ViewBag.Result = "Saved successfully";
            
        ModelState.Clear();
    }

    return View(bankHoliday);
}
```

`BankHolidaySettings.cshtml`:

```
<form asp-controller="Employee"
      asp-action="BankHolidaySettings"
      data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST"
      data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#content"
      class="form-horizontal" role="form"
      data-parsley-validate
      novalidate>
    <table id="holidays" class="table table-bordered table-striped ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <td>Date </td>
               <td>Depot No</td>
               <td>Depot </td>
               <td>Department </td>
               <td>Description </td>
               <td class="hidden">Edit</td>
               <td>Delete</td>
            </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
             @foreach (BankHoliday bankHoliday in ViewBag.BankHolidays)
             {
          <tr>
               <td>@bankHoliday.Holidaydate</td>
               <td>@bankHoliday.DepotNo</td>
              <td>@bankHoliday.DepotName</td>
              <td>@bankHoliday.DepartmentName</td>
              <td>
                  @bankHoliday.Description
                </td>
               <td class="hidden"><a href="#"  
        </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
        </table>
<div class="center-block">
    <button type="submit" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-primary form-control submit">Save</button>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnsubmit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
            var formData = $('form').serialize(); // Serialize the form data
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Employee/BankHolidaySettings",
                data: formData,
                success: function (response) {
                    
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    // Handle the error response
                }
            });
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: using cshtml means the content is rendered in the server side so that we have to go through the get request to reload the page to get the latest data displaying in the page. But since you are using ajax request to post the data rather than the form submit, we can also modifying html content by js executing in the success callback method. This also requires to have the content which used to show in the success callback, so that we might get this data from the post request response, or from the html content we entered.

Answer (score 0):

You are having `cshtml` as the view so that assuming you are having an asp.net core MVC app or razor page web app, both of them are rendering page in the server side, and that's why the updated content require `to select the Bankholiday option again from the menu`. This will send a request to server to call http get request to query the database and render the view once again which would have the latest data.

However, you are using ajax request to post the data and insert it into database. In this scenario, what we can do to realize your requirement has one more option. The easiest way is to trigger the get request which requires you to **add page reload request in the success callback** like `success: function (response) {location.reload();}` . Another way is using html append feature to return the newly added record content in the post request, then **append custom html content to the current table in the success callback**. The code might look like below. If data-inserting won't change the display content, we can directly use the content we pass to the post action and don't need to return the data back.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult BankHolidaySettings(BankHoliday bankHoliday)
{
    //insert successfully here, we can return the model back to the success callback
    return Ok(bankHoliday);
}

success: function (result) {
    console.info(result);
    // location.reload();
    var tempContent = '<tr>'
        + '<td> result.Holidaydate</td>'
        + '<td> result.DepotNo </td>'
        + '<td> result.DepotName</td>'
        + '<td> result.DepartmentName </td>'
        + '<td> result.Description </td>'
        + '<td class="hidden" ><a href="#"></a></td>'
        + '</tr>'
    $("#holidays").find('tbody').append(tempContent);
}
```